# Swift - UICollectionView inside UIScrollView - Auto Layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a scroll view which has a *containerView* on which I put multiple UI components such as labels, buttons etc.

```
        /* START SCROLL VIEW */
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(scrollView)
        
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: frame.width * (22 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (331 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        /* END SCROLL VIEW */

        /* START CONTAINER VIEW */
        containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).priority = .defaultLow
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).priority = .defaultLow
        containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        /* END CONTAINER VIEW */

        ...
        /* START INVITED USERS COLLECTION VIEW */
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        inviteUsersCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        inviteUsersCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(inviteUsersCollectionView)

        inviteUsersCollectionView.delegate = self
        inviteUsersCollectionView.dataSource = self
        inviteUsersCollectionView.register(InviteUsersCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: InviteUsersCollectionViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        inviteUsersCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        inviteUsersCollectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        inviteUsersCollectionView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        inviteUsersCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: frame.width * (34 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
        inviteUsersCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (309 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
        inviteUsersCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inviteUsersLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (27 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
        inviteUsersCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -95).isActive = true
        /* END INVITED USERS COLLECTION VIEW */
}
```

The last sub view in my *containerView* is a *UICollectionView*. I can see that at the bottom, there is an empty space, however the **inviteUsersCollectionView** is not displayed.

What do I need to change?

Comment: What is a guy named 'inviteUsersLabel'?  What is its relationship with the collection guy and others?

Comment: What is 'IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH' and what it's for?  Is your app an iPhone 8 only one?

Comment: Hi @ElTomato. Basically my containerView contains multiple UI components which are placed vertically so that I can scroll down/up. Each next UI component uses the constraints from the one above. This is the reason why my inviteUsersCollectionView uses the bottom constraint of inviteUsersLabel.

Just to say, everything works perfectly except making the inviteUsersCollectionView  visible. Any other UI components is placed where it is supposed to be. I can scroll down/up as I want. 

At the bottom of my scroll view, I can see the space of 95 as I defined it but not the collection view

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out. One line was missing regarding the constraints for my collection view

```
  inviteUsersCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    inviteUsersCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frame.width * (309 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_WIDTH)).isActive = true
    inviteUsersCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inviteUsersLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: frame.height * (27 / IPHONE8_SCREEN_HEIGHT)).isActive = true
    inviteUsersCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95).isActive = true // was missing
    inviteUsersCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
```

The **heightAnchor** wasn't set.

```
inviteUsersCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95).isActive = true
```